# JPQL Query doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Hello i wanna try to to run this Query

```
UPDATE WarmTimeMonitoring wtm
SET wtm.warmTime = (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - wtm.entryDate)*60)+ EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - wtm.entryDate )
WHERE wtm.leavingDate IS NULL
```

When I try the query right on the Database it works

```
UPDATE WARMTIME_MONITORING w
SET w.WARM_TIME = (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - w.ENTRY_DATE)*60)+ EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - w.ENTRY_DATE)
WHERE LEAVING_DATE IS NULL;
```

If I try it with JPQL I get the following error:

> Exception occurred while performing a database query:
>   IllegalArgumentException-> An exception occurred while creating a
>   query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing
>   [UPDATE WarmTimeMonitoring wtm SET wtm.warmTime = (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - wtm.entryDate)*60)+ EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - wtm.entryDate ) WHERE wtm.leavingDate IS NULL ].
>   [68, 85] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression. [131,
>   148] The left expression is not an arithmetic expression.

Can somebody explain me why this happens and how i can fix it?

And yes I checked that warmTime entryDate and leavingDate are callable.

Comment: I guess CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not a valid JPQL property to use...

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is totally valid. EXTRACT is not. HOUR is not. MINUTE is not ... Don't people actually look at JPQL references before forming queries? JPQL != SQL. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#functions

Comment: @NeilStockton Well thank you, I looked around but never found some good examples just the basics.

Comment: @NeilStockton have you a Idea how I could perform that query above with  jpa?

Comment: Depends if you want your JPQL to be portable (i.e only using standard JPQL functions). With standard JPQL you cannot ... just use a JPA native query (SQL) directly. With non-standard JPQL some providers (e.g DataNucleus, the docs I linked) have support for time/date functions ... so you could do things like HOUR(wtm.entryDate) and HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) etc and build it up. See what your provider has available?

Answer (score 0):

As @neil stockon said, the some of the functions are not valid JPQL operations, I suggest, first go for the record and get the information needed to make and update

```
SELECT w.ID, w.ENTRY_DATE from WARMTIME_MONITORING w
WHERE LEAVING_DATE IS NULL;
```

Once you get the id of the record and the entry_date do the operations you need with the date, to conform the new date and do the JPQL update

```
UPDATE WARMTIME_MONITORING w
SET w.WARM_TIME = :time
WHERE ID = :id
```

This could be very inefficient if you have a large amount of data.